# Interpreting the ANOVA output for hierarchical linear regression

Tags: r, regression, anova

I followed [this tutorial](http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.hk/2010/01/r-tutorial-series-basic-hierarchical.html) to learn Hierarchical Linear Regression (HLR) in R, but couldn't understand how to interpret its sample output of `>anova(model1,model2,model3)`

[image]

The tutorial simply says

> each predictor added along the way is making an important contribution to the overall model.

But I would like some more details to **quantify** the contribution of each explanatory variable, like:

1. "UNEM" explains `X` (or `X%`) variance
2. Adding the "HGRAD" variable explains `Y` (or `Y%`) more variance
3. Adding the "INC" variable further explains `Z` (or `Z%`) more variance

So, can I get the value of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` using the above ANOVA table? How? Specifically, what do `Res.Df`, `RSS`, `Sum of Sq` mean in this ANOVA table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at % variance farther up in the tutorial where the R-squared values are reported. You look at the model for the quantity of variance explained and the test (`anova`) for whether the increase across model complexity is significant.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I can use `>summary(model)` for each individual model to see its R-squared (which is the variance explained), and compared the differences between R-squared. Then using `>anova(model1, model2, model3)`, I can further evaluate whether the differences of R-squared are significant. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused about `variance` and `deviance`. I already revised my question.

Comment: To your first comment, yes.